# Is it safe to gather references to JDBC objects and close them in a loop?

Tags: java, jdbc, resources

So I'm trying to refactor some code which creates JDBC objects in a loop and didn't close them out cleanly. My first thought is to create a `LinkedList` to store the prepared statements, result sets, etc., and then close them in a loop inside a `finally` block. So, the approach is like:

```
Connection conn = null;
LinkedList<PreparedStatement> statements = new LinkedList<PreparedStatement>();
LinkedList<ResultSet> results = new LinkedList<ResultSet>();

    try {
        conn = database.getConnection(); 

        for (String i : arr1) {
            for (String j : arr2) {

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                statements.add(stmt);

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(...);
                results.add(rs);

                // ...work...

            }
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    finally {
        // close all result sets..
        for (ResultSet rs : (ResultSet[])results.toArray()) {
            if (rs != null)   try { rs.close();   } catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }

        for (Statement stmt : (Statement[])statements.toArray()) {
            if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }

        if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
   }
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Will this end up causing some kind of leak or problem? Thanks in advance, and please let me know if this belongs rather on codereview.se or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is IMHO a bad idea for at least three reasons:

1. Resources aren't cleaned up immediately when they are no longer used. `ResultSet` is an expensive resource and I am not even sure whether you can have several opened result sets on one connection (*update*: you can, see comments).
2. In this approach you are opening multiple resources at once, which might lead to excessive and unnecessary usage of database resources and peaks. Especially dangerous if the number of iterations is high.
3. A special case of previous point is memory - if either `Statement` or `ResultSet` holds a lot of memory, holding an unnecessary reference to several such objects wil cause excessive memory usage.

That being said consider using already built and safe utility classes like [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). I know it comes from Spring framework, but you can use it outside of the container (just pass an instance of `DataSource`) and never worry about closing JDBC resources again.

Comment: Just a comment: Yes, you can have several opened ResultSet objects using one connection. That said, if you really need them, you should close them as soon as you are done with them (at the very least, at the end of the loop).

Comment: @Barranka: thanks for clarification. I thought a `ResultSet` represents an "*open*" stream of records so it is not possible to have several opened at once.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a leak, but I could see issues.

My experience with Oracle JDBC (specifically) has taught me that the very best thing to do when handling JDBC resources is to close them in exactly the reverse order that you opened them. Every time. As soon as possible.

Collecting them for later cleanup, and releasing them in a different order may cause an issue. I can't sight a specific example, but Oracle seems to be the one that bit me the hardest on this in the past. It is good that you release ResultSet, before Statement, before Connection, but it may not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed bad, because it may force the database to hold on to resources you're no longer using.  I've seen cases where failure to close Statement or ResultSet objects (can't remember which; possibly both) caused cursor leak errors in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You should do all your work in the `try` and only close the connection in the `finally`. That is the standard pattern.

Comment: Oh yeah... so you are! Sorry about that :) I didn't read the code carefully enough. As long as the close connection is guaranteed to work, you're good.